# User input and months with objects and classes

Tags: java, oop

I am having a problem with refining my user input in my code and having a problem creating a new method (GetMonthName) that returns the name of the month based on the number contained in Monthnum field. Also my professor states: An equals method that accepts a Month object as an argument. If the
argument object holds the same data as the calling object, this method should return
TRUE. Otherwise, it should return FALSE. I am uncertain of if the argument object holds the same data as the calling object and how to go about this. My code is as follows:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class testObjectsAndClasses {
    public static void main(String args[]){

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please enter a month number");
        int monthNumber = input.nextInt();
        Monthnum inputMonthName = new Monthnum(monthNumber);


        System.out.println("Enter Month Name, Please Capitalize first Letter");
        String monthName = input.next();
        Monthnum inputMonthNumber = new Monthnum(monthName);

    }
}
class Monthnum{

    public int Monthnum;
    public String monthName;


    public Monthnum(){
        Monthnum = 1;
        monthName = "January";
    }
    public Monthnum(int whichMonth){
        Monthnum = whichMonth;
        if (whichMonth == 1){
            monthName = "January";
            System.out.println("January");
        }
        else if (whichMonth == 2){
            monthName = "February";
            System.out.println("February");
        }
        else if (whichMonth == 3){
            monthName = "March";
            System.out.println("March");
        }
        else if (whichMonth == 4){
            monthName = "April";
            System.out.println("April");
        }
        else if (whichMonth == 5){
            monthName = "May";
            System.out.println("May");
        }
        else if (whichMonth == 6){
            monthName = "June";
            System.out.println("June");
        }
        else if (whichMonth == 7){
            monthName = "July";
            System.out.println("July");
        }
        else if (whichMonth == 8){
            monthName = "August";
            System.out.println("August");
        }
        else if (whichMonth == 9){
            monthName = "September";
            System.out.println("September");
        }
        else if (whichMonth == 10){
            monthName = "October";
            System.out.println("October");
        }
        else if (whichMonth == 11){
            monthName = "November";
            System.out.println("November");
        }
        else if (whichMonth == 12){
            monthName = "December";
            System.out.println("December");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Invalid input. Please Capitalize the first letter of the month");
        }

    } //end of cons

    public Monthnum(String whichMonth){
        if (whichMonth.equals("January")){
            Monthnum = 1;
            System.out.println(Monthnum);
        }
        else if (whichMonth.equals("February")){
            Monthnum = 2;
            System.out.println(Monthnum);
        }
        else if (whichMonth.equals("March")){
            Monthnum = 3;
            System.out.println(Monthnum);
        }
        else if (whichMonth.equals("April")){
            Monthnum = 4;
            System.out.println(Monthnum);
        }
        else if (whichMonth.equals("May")){
            Monthnum = 5;
            System.out.println(Monthnum);
        }
        else if (whichMonth.equals("June")){
            Monthnum = 6;
            System.out.println(Monthnum);
        }
        else if (whichMonth.equals("July")){
            Monthnum = 7;
            System.out.println(Monthnum);
        }
        else if (whichMonth.equals("August")){
            Monthnum = 8;
            System.out.println(Monthnum);
        }
        else if (whichMonth.equals("September")){
            Monthnum = 9;
            System.out.println(Monthnum);
        }
        else if (whichMonth.equals("October")){
            Monthnum = 10;
            System.out.println(Monthnum);
        }
        else if (whichMonth.equals("November")){
            Monthnum = 11;
            System.out.println(Monthnum);
        }
        else if (whichMonth.equals("December")){
            Monthnum = 12;
            System.out.println(Monthnum );
        }
        else
            System.out.println("Invalid input");
    }
    int GetMonthnum (int currentMonthNumber){
    Monthnum = currentMonthNumber;
            return currentMonthNumber;
    }
  //public String getMonthName (String monthName)

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of having a large amount of if and else if statements you should consider using an array of month names, in which each name corresponds to its index. Now for the constructors; for the constructor handling an index (store it), and simply set the name to that of names[index - 1] (-1 since youre using 1 for January not 0). For the constructor handling a name (store it), and simply find the index of the name in the array + 1.

Making a method to return whether or not the months are equal can be done by just equating their names.

Think of classes as something that identifies a type of object. It shouldn't really be called MonthNum because it stores data for a month not the number of the month.

Also, if you want the user to be able to enter month names in any case, e.g. FebRUARY, then just use name.equalsIgnoreCase(otherName).

Another thing, in Objected Oriented Programming there's a concept called Data Hiding or Encapsulation which disallows a classes data to be accessed externally but only through methods (getters and setters). Notice how the variables index and name are private not public while the methods getName and getIndex are public.

```
public class Month{
    private static final String[] names = new String[]{"January", "February"... "December"};
    private int index;
    private String name;
    public Month(int index){
      this.index = index;
      name = names[index - 1];
    }
    public Month(String name){
      this.name = name;
      index = java.util.Arrays.asList(names).indexOf(name) + 1;
    }
    public int getIndex(){
      return index;
    }
    public String getName(){
      return name;
    }
    public Boolean equals(Month month){
      return this.name.equals(month.getName());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for simplicity you can do something like this

```
public String getMonthName (int num){
    switch(num){
        case (1):{
            return "January";
        }
        case (2):{
            return "February";
        }
        case (3):{
            return "March";
        }
        case (4):{
            return "April";
        }
        case (5):{
            return "May";
        }
        case (6):{
            return "June";
        }
        case (7):{
            return "July";
        }
        case (8):{
            return "August";
        }
        case (9):{
            return "September";
        }
        case (10):{
            return "October";
        }
        case (11):{
            return "November";
        }
        case (12):{
            return "December";
        }
    }
    return "invalid month Number";
}
```

or

```
public String getMonthName (int num){

    String[] months = {"January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"};
    if(num<1 || num>12){
        return "invalid Month No";
    }
    return months[--num];
}
```